# include a mixin in all scss files

Tags: sass, include, scss-mixins

So I have a react application that has a main 'App.scss' file that is basically only including other scss files like this:

```
@import "./base/mixins.scss";
@import "./components/hamburger.scss";
@import "./components/sidebarmenu.scss";
@import "./components/page-toolbar.scss";
....
```

The first is a mixin file that I would like to use in some of other scss files. I know I can import it in each and every file I want to use it, but how can I just import the file once and suddenly all the scss files know about it?

Currently I get this error

```
@include box-shadow(0, 1px, 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
        ^
No mixin named box-shadow`
```

this is my file structure by the way:

```
| App.scss
| components
    | _hamburger.scss
    | _sidebarmenu.scss
    | _page-toolbar.scss
| base
    | _mixins.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

Try @import in style.scss

You can import angular.json "styles" too.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your problem is the way you call your mixin. A solution for this would be:

1. Import the `mixin.scss` file in the file you want to use the mix in in:

   ```
   @use "src/styles/mixins.scss"
   ```

   and be careful to import it before importing your variables, in case you have any.
2. ```
   @include mixin.box-shadow(0, 1px, 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
   ```